# using jq for parsing chrome bookmarks to csv

Tags: python, bookmarks, jq

Is it possible to parse Chrome bookmarks with jq in one line?
(for csv output)

With `jq '.roots.other.children[]'` Bookmarks
I get separate lines

Comment: You need to post input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome bookmark format is not "flat" so it's not obvious what CSV output you want, but starting with .roots.other.children[] as you suggest, here's a start:

```
jq -r '.roots.other.children[]
       | [.date_added,.id,.name,.sync_transaction_version,.type,.url,
          (.meta_info|tostring)]
       | @csv'
```

Notice how `tostring` is used here to "flatten" `.meta_info`.  Notice also that the fields of interest have been specified explicitly -- this is to guard against the possibility that their ordering may not always be uniform within the bookmarks file.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: My problem is the NOT-flatten structure  of the google bookmark file, I will try it to solve with python and json. The tipp with @csv and tostring helps me!

Comment: Except maybe for having to learn a bit of jq, it would be easier with jq